# How to launch a function(this) from an html element automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I have is a bunch of:

```
<div class="panel-heading" id="@l.restaurant.id">
```

As you can see the ID of every DIV is a variable that the function will use.
For exemple if I do this :

```
<div class="panel-heading" id="@l.restaurant.id" onclick="fun(this)"  >
```

The function works when I click the DIV, but I want that function to start as soon the page loads without me doing a thing.

Comment: Why can't you gather the element in your function if it's an `id`? Why do you need `this`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to `fun` all `panel-heading` on load, then try

```
$(function() {
  $(".panel-heading").each(function() {
    fun(this);
  });
});
```

If you need to only run `fun` on divs that [contain](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) *restaurant* in the id, change the selector - `$('.panel-heading[id*="restaurant"]')`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element by id, and run you `func` on the element itself.

```
 fun(document.getElementById('@l.restaurant.id'))
```

If you use jQuery you can do it on page load

```
 $(function(){
     fun(document.\getElementById('@l.restaurant.id'))
 })
```

This is a short way to bind to document onload.

```
 $(document).on('ready',function(){
        // Your code
 ])
```

### Example

Here is an example of a button that clicked on page load. When the user click the button, the background color of the button need to page change to blue. See that this is happen automatically.

```js
function fun(element) {
  element.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
}

$(function() {
  fun(document.getElementById('btn1'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click a button, to change it's color:
<button id=btn1 onclick=fun(this)>btn1</button>
<button id=btn2 onclick=fun(this)>btn2</button>
```

### More info...

It is not best practice, to bind event in the HTML code. it's always better to do this:

```
 $('#button_id').on('click',func)
```

When you do this, your `func`, will always have the element that you clicked as the context (`this`).

Then you can do:

```
 function(func){
           // this== document.getElementById('button_id')
 }
```

[Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)

Comment: `$(function() {});` is shorter

Comment: I can't do that because the variable "l" isnt known in the script part.
Moreover I have a loop  @foreach (var l in @ViewBag.list) I can't make a function for every one.

Comment: In that example can u make the fun(this) works for the two buttons directly without the onclick event?

Comment: Then you can use jQuery *match. for example $('[id*=restaurant]').click()  This is much all elements that the id that contain `restaurant`

Comment: You also can click the first `panel-heading` class by doing: $('.panel-hading').first().click() on page load

Answer (score -1):

Use a load event listener :)

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  //the page has loaded; call your function
});
```